# Как настроить Webpack для работы Yandex Maps API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, yandex-maps-api, webpack

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настраивать Webpack для работы с api Яндекс.карты?

Я добавил в зависимости `webpack`, создал `module.exports` в файле **webpack.config.js**.

```
module.exports = {
  externalsType: 'script',
  externals: {
      ymaps3: ["https://api-maps.yandex.ru/3.0/?apikey=fd&lang=ru_RU", "ymaps3"]
  }
};
```

Однако, ничего не работает после того, как я пытаюсь импортировать модуль `ymaps3` в своем компоненте. Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
import * as ymaps3 from 'ymaps3';

ymaps3.ready.then(() => {
  const {YMaps} = ymaps3;
  new YMaps({});
});
```

IDE просто не видит этот пакет.

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: Из описания непонятно, вы скрыли от нас api-ключ (с заранее привязанным доменом) под apikey=fd или забыли его получить, подождать сутки и прописать в вызов. Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @YaCor' api-key скрыл, ибо просят никому его не разглашать

Comment: Домен в настройках ключа подвязан? API 3.0 без привязки не запустится. И referer IDE при подключении API тоже обязана передавать. Передаёт? Если уж решаете через SO, а не поддержку, стоит хотя бы детали диагностики приводить, чтобы сузить рамки возможной причины.

Comment: @YaCor', спасибо большое за отзывчивость! Решил проблему иным способом